# Rust Integration Tests Structure

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to split my integration tests into multiple files (because it's getting long). This can be easily done:

```
/tests/
    /data/      // <- dataset for testing
    a_tests.rs // <- this contains "common" functions which I'd like to use in b_tests.rs
    b_tests.rs
```

However, `a_tests.rs` contains some functions which I'd like to use in `b_tests.rs`. For example a common Lazy once_cell which reads the data file only once. And also a `fn common_func(_)` which does assertion based on numerical comparisons of the results.

So how do I import objects from `a_tests.rs` in `b_tests.rs`?

Comment: See the [Submodules in Integration Tests](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch11-03-test-organization.html#submodules-in-integration-tests) section of the Rust manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Rust documentation on [integration tests](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests) each file in the `tests` directory is compiled into a separate crate, but:

> Files in subdirectories of the tests directory don’t get compiled as separate crates or have sections in the test output.
> So you can have this file structure:

```
/tests/
    /common/
        mod.rs
    /data/
    a_tests.rs
    b_tests.rs
```

Then move your shared functions from `a_tests.rs` into `common/mod.rs` and you can import them into `a_tests.rs` and `b_tests.rs` via `mod common;`